# How to genrate a unique key for user from database fields using php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create keys based on the information provided by the User. For eg If user insert his name,phone,country,some other information then my code should concatenate some fields and store a unique key into the same user table where i have field key. I hope you understand my issue.I am new to codeigniter and have used the base model by Joost Van.

The Controller Code:

```
<?php
class Reseller extends Admin_Controller
{

public function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
    public function reseller ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/users'; //Users variable stores the suvbview 
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}


public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {



$data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','created','modified','status'));


        $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);


        $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);
        for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
            {
            $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
            $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
             }



        redirect('admin/reseller');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}


public function delete ($id)
{
    $this->reseller_m->delete($id);
    redirect('admin/reseller');
}


}
```

The Model:

```
<?php
class Reseller_M extends MY_Model {


protected $_table_name = 'reseller';
protected $_order_by = 'name';
protected $_timestamps = TRUE;
public $rules = array(
    'email' => array(
        'field' => 'email', 
        'label' => 'Email', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'password' => array(
        'field' => 'password', 
        'label' => 'Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required'
    ),

);
public $rules_admin = array(
    'name' => array(
        'field' => 'name', 
        'label' => 'Name', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'email' => array(
        'field' => 'email', 
        'label' => 'Email', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email|xss_clean'
    ), 
    'password' => array(
        'field' => 'password', 
        'label' => 'Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_confirm]'
    ),
    'password_confirm' => array(
        'field' => 'password_confirm', 
        'label' => 'Confirm password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
    ),
    'sip_username' => array(
        'field' => 'sip_username', 
        'label' => 'Sip Username', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|'
    ),
    'sip_password' => array(
        'field' => 'sip_password', 
        'label' => 'SIP Password', 
        'rules' => 'trim|required|'
    ),


);

function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();

}




public function get_new(){
    $user = new stdClass();

//          $user->id = '';
    $user->sip_username='';
    $user->sip_password='';
    $user->key='';
    $user->allocation_block='';
    $user->name='';
    $user->email = '';      
    $user->password = '';
    $user->phone=''; 
    $user->user_num=''; 
    $user->address = '';
    $user->status = '';
    $user->country=''; 
    $user->created = '';
    $user->modified  = '';
    $user->balance = '';
    return $user;
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

}

public function get_user_profile(){
    $this->db->select('id,sip_password,sip_username,phone,key,address,country,created,modified,user_num,allocation_block,status,email, name, balance');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('reseller', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
    return $query->result();
}

function insert_item($key)

{
    $this->reseller = $key;

    $this->db->set($this->reseller, $this);
}




public function hash ($string)
{
    return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
}


public function loggedin ()
{
    return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
}

}
```

The Base Model Where CURD Functions are defined

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

protected $_table_name = '';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = '';
public $rules = array();
protected $_timestamps = FALSE;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}


public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }


    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL){




    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}

public function delete($id){
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);

    if (!$id) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
}
}
```

Comment: Just pull all of the information from the database and put it into one long string.. "{$this->user}-{$this->countrycode}..." etc.

Comment: So at the time when reseller is being created i need to concatenate all other fields variable into a single field eg $key=$name.$countrycode.$reseller_id.... and so on ?

Comment: is it possible to do this at the time of user creation? so that i can get the key as soon as the reseller in  created ?

Comment: please help because i am not sure how to do this in codeigniter. Its possible in Core PHP but i dont know how to do this in Codeigniter.

Comment: atleast tell me where i can do this join or concatenation in model or controller